# c++ - Undefined reference to <function name> when using multiple header files

Tags: c++, header

I am new to C++ programming and I have been stucked in this for hours.

I have three header files: A.h, B.h and common.h and two .cpp files: A.cpp, B.cpp.

## A.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include"B.h"

class AA{
    public:
        void fun();
};

#endif
```

## B.h

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H
#include <iostream>
#include "common.h"

using namespace std;

class BB{
    public: 
        void fun2();
};
#endif
```

## common.h

```
extern int c;
```

## A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"


void AA::fun(){
    cout<<"A"<<endl;
}
```

## B.cpp

```
#include "B.h" 

void BB::fun2(){
    cout<<"FUN 2"<<endl;
}
```

## main.cpp

```
#include "A.h"

int main(){
    int c = 5;
    AA a;
    a.fun();

    return 0;
}
```

Error: undefined reference to `AA::fun()'

Why am I getting this error? Can anyone explain it? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: How do you build your application? Do you build with *all* source files, or all object files generated from the source files?

Comment: Also note that `extern int c;` declares a *global* variable, which is very different from the *local* variable with the same name in the `main` function.

Comment: I built this using gcc c++11 compiler in Codeblocks.

Comment: I got this error even without including common.h in b.h.

Comment: And are all source files listed as source file in the project list? It's not enough to exist on the disk, you need to have them in the actual project tree.

Comment: Thanks. This solved the issue.